# Control Adobe Reader plugin

Tags: javascript, pdf, plugins, web, adobe-reader

is there any way to control the adobe reader pdf plugin on a website better than simply passing those "open parameters" that I cannot influence anymore once the document is loaded?

Thanks!

Leo